# Fade in and out multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a photo gallery type effect but instead of a carousel slider, I want to just fade in and out.

**What I've tried so far:**

```js
// To hide all but the first image when page load
$('.homeBanners .helloContainer:gt(0)').hide();
$(".homeBanners").mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('homeBannerScrollTime'));
}).mouseleave(function() {

    var homeBannerElement = $(this),
        homeBannerScrollTime = setInterval(function() {
            $('.homeBanners :first-child').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(500).end().appendTo('.homeBanners');
        }, 1000);

    //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
    homeBannerElement.data('homeBannerScrollTime', homeBannerScrollTime);
});
```

```css
.homeBanners 
{
    width: 2000px!important;
    height: 400px;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}

.homeBanners img 
{
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 400px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.hello
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello2
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello3
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello4
{
    background-color: purple;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello5
{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello6
{
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}


.homeBanners img:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homeBanners">
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello"></div>
        <div class="hello hello2"></div>
        <div class="hello hello3"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello hello4"></div>
        <div class="hello hello5"></div>
        <div class="hello hello6"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**What I want to happen:**

**---- First Run ----**

--- Shown container ---

```
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello"></div>
        <div class="hello hello2"></div>
        <div class="hello hello3"></div>
    </div>
```

--- Hidden container ---

```
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello hello4"></div>
        <div class="hello hello5"></div>
        <div class="hello hello6"></div>
    </div>
```

**--- Fade in and out ---**

--- Shown container (fade out) ---

```
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello"></div>
        <div class="hello hello2"></div>
        <div class="hello hello3"></div>
    </div>
```

--- Hidden container (fade in) ---

```
    <div class="helloContainer">
        <div class="hello hello4"></div>
        <div class="hello hello5"></div>
        <div class="hello hello6"></div>
    </div>
```

Hope this is enough information for everyone to understand, If you need anymore information please just comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Have one div hidden with CSS (`display:none`), you will have to give it a unique identifier, obviously.

using jQuery, toggle the two Divs like:

```
$('helloContainer').fadeToggle();
```

Comment: I want to do it without user interaction, so without having to press a toggle, and I don't really want to have unique identifiers for them.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett `fadeToggle();` doens't mean you have to press "a toggle". It means it Toggles between On, and Off. All you need to do is put it inside a `setInterval(function({ ... }, 5000);` or something, which would make it autofire every 5000 ms. Sorry, I just presumed you would have known this.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid now, Of course I know of this. My brain isn't functioning this morning :) Would you be able to provide a example of doing it without unique identifiers?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett lol no worries mate :) as for not having unique identifiers, that is also fine. Just hide all the divs with jQuery on page load. `$('.helloContainer').css('display','none');` ( that way if JS fails to load at least you will still be able to see the pictures ). then you can show the first one `$('.helloContainer').first()` using  either `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeToggle()`, `.css('display','inline')` etc. then start your setInterval with the fadeToggle :)

Comment: the setInterval with fadeToggle makes it act very strange

Comment: why, what seems to be happening. can you jsfiddle it?

Comment: Sorry it's just me being picky with it showing all the divs before it showing either the first lot of divs or the second lot of divs :) It's working how you expect it to be working

Comment: Oh, in that case @ChrisBeckett it's not working how I meant. You should run an IIFE which instantly sets the css to hidden for all of the divs, and then displays the first div. then, seperately, inside a setInterval loop, you set the fadeToddle :)

Comment: @ChrisBeckett You had any luck with that mate?

Comment: Morning Josh :) It works fine, but then I get the same problem of all the images show up and then fade way to show only the ones selected. However this little problem only occurs a few times. So like 2 out of 5 times. Do you know why this could be happening, could it just be a problem with the speed of transitions?